# In Jquery how can i find the first instance of the class below or above a button?

Tags: jquery, class, find

I have the following html

```
<span class="above">Value</span>
<button id="SaveButton">Save</button>

Some random HTML

<input type="text" value="Test" />

<span class="below">Value 3</span>
```

and I want to reference the spans that have the **below** and **above** classes in the click event of the button.  I thought find() would do it but i see that is only for items that are children of a container DOM element

I want something like this . .

```
     $(".SaveButton").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            alert($(this).find(".above").html());
            alert($(this).find(".below").html());

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not seem to be descendants, so you could use .siblings() to find `.above` & `.below`

```
  $(".SaveButton").live("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert($(this).siblings(".above").html());
      alert($(this).siblings(".below").html());
  });
```

**Documentation:** http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the dom up and down pretty easily with [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Further, each of those can take a selector, so you could do:

```
$(this).prev('span');
```

As Anton points out, there's also `prevAll` and `nextAll` which will return an array of the elements before or after matching the selector used.